# error when writing R package

Tags: r

I'm writing an R package and use R/sysdata.rda. After I run `devtools:document()`,

```
Updating InjurySeverityScore documentation
Loading InjurySeverityScore
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
  cannot open compressed file 'sysdata.rda', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Wonder if anyone could give some hints?

Comment: It seems `readChar()` cannot find `sysdata.rda` are you sure it's calling the right path?

Comment: En, I think I'm calling the right path. The package name was identified correctly.

Comment: Well, it turns that I write `load("sysdata.rda")` in one of the code. After removing that line, it all worked out. I don't need to load that rda and could use directly.